# Update values using columns of another file

Tags: replace, awk

I want to exchange the values in file A with the values of file B if there is a match between the value of file A and part of a string in file B.

File A

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
```

File B

```
1 A0:xxxx:z:y
1 A2:xxxx:z:y
1 A3:xxxx:z:y
1 CC:xxx1:z:y
1 A1:xxxx:z:y
1 CC:xxx2:z:y
```

Desired output

```
A1:xxxx:z:y
A2:xxxx:z:y
A3:xxxx:z:y
A4
A5
```

I'm trying to use the code below but is not working.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} {split($2, b, ":"); if(b[1] in a) print $2; else print a[$1]}' fileA fileB > output.txt
```

Ps1: I had seen some answers about this issue before and I'm trying to apply those to my problem so, if possible, I want to understand why my code is wrong. (Mainly, because I want to use the core of this code to do another tasks as exchange values between files is usual).

Ps2: I guess the problem is in the way to access the values in a. I tried to use a[$1]=$1 and $2=a[$1] but both failed. So how is the best way to retrieve the values of columns in the first file when I'm processing the second one?

Ps3: During the tests I noticed a strange behavior. If I ask to print a string (eg. "unchanged" or b[1]) instead of a[$1] the script seems to work well, (I can see the match and the unmatched columns and I can check the true matches using grep), but when I use a[$1] the code print $2 in some unmatched columns (and I cannot trace the error because near identical columns as the last two in the file B returns different results, for one there is an incorrect print and for the other no).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: New answer for update to question.

With the new understanding of the question, it's probably easier to process the files in the other order (fileB first)

```
$ cat fileA
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5


$ cat fileB
1 A0:xxxx:z:y
1 A2:xxxx:z:y
1 A3:xxxx:z:y
1 CC:xxx1:z:y
1 A1:xxxx:z:y
1 CC:xxx2:z:y


$ cat jw.awk
# Process fileB first, creating an array with elements such as
# a["A0"] = "A0:xxxx:z:y", a["A2"] = "A2:xxxx:z:y", etc.    
NR == FNR { split($2, b, ":"); a[b[1]] = $2; next }

# Now process fileA, printing either the line from fileB if the
#  key is found, otherwise the line from fileA    
{ if ($1 in a) print a[$1]; else print }


$ awk -f jw.awk fileB fileA
A1:xxxx:z:y
A2:xxxx:z:y
A3:xxxx:z:y
A4
A5
```

Comment: Thank you @jas!
I also tried this before ask here: awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR];next} {split($2, b, ":"); if(b[1] in a) print $2; else print a[NR]}' fileA fileB > output.txt but didn't work (for some reason seems that I only can access values in FNR - or the current file). But I cannot understand why I can't access the value of array a using the key $1? Isn't array a an associative array? Unfortunately, worked for the example (I tested as well) but didn't work for my real data (only printed the unmatched rows and printed blank lines for all fields of file B not in A).

Comment: I'm trying to discover what's the problem as the only difference is that my real data has more columns than I described in the example.

Comment: I added some info which might help, and I'll also pass along some advice that Ed Morton, one of the top contributors to awk questions here, likes to give: "Get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins".

Comment: Superb @jas, now I could understand the issues. Many thanks!

Comment: But I guess the problem remains, if the match is not in the same line in both files, the script will fail, right? (eg. if 1 A2:xxxx:z:y is in the 5th row, or 1 A1:xxxx:z:y is in 6th column). This is why I tried to compare the values. Anyway, I updated the question to make it explicit.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking you only wanted to compare the corresponding values in the same row. Let's see how to fix it then ...

Comment: See edit with new answer and let's see if we're getting closer :)

Comment: It's working like a charm! Many thanks! As I understood I cannot process both files in the same time when I need to create an associative array for 1st file (and retrieve info from it). Seems that I only can access data in an array fully processed or in FNR. (btw I read "Reading Input files" and "Arrays" in the book but this seems to be a concept beyond it covers, but was very useful, ty).

Comment: Great! And yes, awk always reads all the records from the first file before any from the second (and etc. if there are more files).